# How to convert python class to table postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, orm, psycopg2

I have been looking for information on how to make a table in a database from a Python class for a very long time, but I have not found a good explanation

I was looking for examples, but the descriptions are limited and the examples are very difficult to understand

I want to implement without using a framework such as sqlalchemy

```
class User:
   tablename = "user"
   name = CharField(..)



def create_table(
    sql_query: str, 
    conn: psycopg2.extensions.connection, 
    cur: psycopg2.extensions.cursor
) -> None:
    try:
        # Execute the table creation query
        cur.execute(sql_query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
        print(f"Query: {cur.query}")
        conn.rollback()
        cur.close()
    else:
        # To take effect, changes need be committed to the database
        conn.commit()
```

class User -> postgres table

Comment: why?  Sqlalchemy is exactly this with way fewer bugs and way more features

Comment: I don't need this. I want to see how it all works without orm. Otherwise I would use Sqlalchemy

Comment: What doesn't work in your code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go down this route take a look at [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html):

```
@attr.s
class C(object):
    x = attr.ib(type=int)
    y = attr.ib(type=str)

flds = attr.fields(C)

flds
(Attribute(name='x', default=NOTHING, validator=None, repr=True, eq=True, order=True, hash=None, init=True, metadata=mappingproxy({}), type=<class 'int'>, converter=None, kw_only=False),
 Attribute(name='y', default=NOTHING, validator=None, repr=True, eq=True, order=True, hash=None, init=True, metadata=mappingproxy({}), type=<class 'str'>, converter=None, kw_only=False))

flds[0].name
'x'
flds[0].type 
int
```

For adding metadata e.g. table name see [Metadata](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/extending.html?highlight=metadata#metadata).

You would have to create a conversion code that takes Python types and maps to SQL type strings.

Honestly my recommendation is to not go this route with your own home brewed solution. There are a lot of ORMs out there that will do this for you, without the headache of keeping your code up to date. If you want something smaller then SQLAlchemy take a look at [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/).

My own preference is to keep my DDL as SQL scripts using [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/).

Comment: This is something strange. I wrote above that I do not want to use ready-made orm

Answer (score 0):

You will have to connect to the database and use postgresSQL to tell the database how to structure the table(s). Simply make the table attributes the same as your class attributes.

Your table SQL will look something like:

```
 CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] table_name (
       class_attribute datatype(length) column_constraint,
       class_attribute datatype(length) column_constraint,
       class_attribute datatype(length) column_constraint,
       table_constraints
    );
```

If you want to write your own interface to the postgresSQL DBMS you will need a very good understanding of relation databases. If you decide you want a ready-made solution try [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/) out.

Comment: This I understand. I connected to the database via psycopg2 made the cursor made the connection

Comment: You have to run the SQL on the database to create the table. You can use `cursor.execute("SQL")` to create the table.

Comment: I mean. How to convert this to a table postgres. `class User: tablename = 'user' name = CharField()...etc to table.how to make a table in a database from a python class